# I'm getting wrong record in sql select query

Tags: mysql

I want to select data from MySQL. And also wanted to do some calculation at query execution time. I have two SQL tables:

**Loan Table :**

```
loan_id|Customer_name|Total_amount|Collector
1000   |Sashika      |55000       |Kapoor
1001   |Amell        |11000       |Kapoor
1002   |Oliver       |15000       |Kapoor
```

**Settlement Table :**

```
Sett_id|Loan_id|Amount
a123    |1000    |1000
b123    |1000    |1000
```

Specially I wanted point that **1001 & 1002 loans not yet received any settlements.** I want to select loans **by collector name**. and select should be like this:

**Output Table**

```
Loan_ID| Customer_Name|Total_Amount|Total_Received|Total_Due
1000   |Sashika       |55000       |2000          |53000
1001   |Amell         |11000       |0             |11000
1002   |Oliver        |15000       |0             |15000
```

To do that I used below select query. But It only show 1000(loan_id) record.
I think because only 1000(loan_id) has settlement record. 1001 & 1002 hadn't any records that's why it doesn't show. But my requirement is load all loans details like above **output Table** .

Currently I use below code:

```
select
loan.loan_id as 'Loan ID'
   ,loan.customer_name as 'Customer Name'
   ,loan.total_amount as 'Total Amount'
   ,ifnull(sum(settlement.amount),0) as 'Total Received'
   ,((loan.total_amount)-ifnull(sum(settlement.amount), 0))as 'Total Due'
from loan
inner join settlement  on  loan.loan_id =  settlement.loan_id
where loan.collector_name='kapoor'
group by loan.loan_id
```

Like I said It doesn't show 1001, 1002 (`loan_id`'s) records like **Output Table**

Comment: `Total_Received` for `Loan_ID  1000` is **2000** ? isn't it supposed to be **3000**? `LEFT JOIN` is supposed to be applied in this case.

Comment: sorry I edited that. It's mistake

Answer (score 1):

A left join between the above two tables is required in this case.

```
select
 loan.loan_id AS 'Loan ID',
 loan.customer_name AS 'Customer Name',
 loan.total_amount AS 'Total Amount',
 ifnull(sum(settlement.amount),0) AS 'Total Received',
((loan.total_amount)-ifnull(sum(settlement.amount), 0))as 'Total Due'

FROM
    loan
LEFT JOIN settlement ON loan.loan_id = settlement.loan_id
WHERE
    loan.collector_name = 'kapoor'
GROUP BY    loan.loan_id
```

Answer (score 0):

`INNER JOIN` will never show the loan_ids that are not found in the settlement table. Use `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

You need to sue a `LEFT JOIN` to return the data you want as the `loan_id`'s  `1001` and `1002` don't exist in the Settlement table.

Also in the table structure you say `collector` in the current code you use `collector_name`, in my code below and SQL Fiddle example i have used `collector`.

```
SELECT 
l.loan_id AS 'Loan ID',
l.customer_name AS 'Customer Name',
l.total_amount AS 'Total Amount',
IFNULL(SUM(s.amount),0) AS 'Total Received',
((l.total_amount) - IFNULL(SUM(s.amount), 0)) AS 'Total Due'
FROM loan l
LEFT JOIN settlement s on l.loan_id =  s.loan_id
WHERE l.collector_name = 'kapoor'
GROUP BY l.loan_id
```

Output:

```
loan_id Customer_name   Total_amount    Total Received  Total Due
1000    Sashika         55000           2000            53000
1001    Amell           11000           0               11000
1002    Oliver          15000           0               15000
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe704/2/0